# How can I access a tab bar item by pressing a nav bar button

Tags: ios, swift, uiviewcontroller, uitabbarcontroller, uibarbuttonitem

I've created a `CustomTabBarController` class with 5 buttons that work perfectly fine.

Each button triggers an individual view controller.

Example: home button triggers the homeViewController and shows it on the screen perfectly.

In the `homeViewController`, I've created a right bar button item with the following code:

```
let homeButton = UIBarButtonItem(image: UIImage(named: "HomeButton"), style: .plain, target: self, action:#selector(homeViewController.goToHomeVC)

self.navigationItem.rightBarButtonItem  = homeButton

    func goToHomeVC(sender: UIButton) {
         // Go to home page (tab bar index 0)
}
```

How can I implement my tappedHome function so it can access the tab bar item (Home) so it triggers the homeViewController and shows it on the screen?

Answer (score 0):

Basically, That is not actual `UITabBarController` so, **You have to maintain the push and pop manually.**

Here the code of push and pop that will help you to move between your five view-controller classes.

```
func pushIfRequired(className:AnyClass) {

    if (UIViewController.self != className) {
        print("Your pushed class must be child of UIViewController")
        return
    }
    let storyboard : UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
    var isPopDone = false
    let mainNavigation = UIApplication.shared.delegate?.window??.rootViewController as? UINavigationController
    let viewControllers = mainNavigation!.viewControllers
    for vc in viewControllers {
        if (type(of: vc) == className) {
            mainNavigation?.popToViewController(vc, animated: true)
            isPopDone =  true
            break
        }
    }
    if isPopDone == false{
        let instanceSignUp = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: NSStringFromClass(className)) // Identifier must be same name as class
        mainNavigation?.pushViewController(instanceSignUp, animated: true)
    }
}
```

**Uses**

```
pushIfRequired(className: FirstTabVC.self)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you don't mind checking the parent to get to your CustomTabBarController,

```
func navButtonPressedAction() {
    guard let tabVC = self.parent?.parent as? UITabBarController else { return }
    tabVC.selectedIndex = 2 //Index of the tab bar item here
}
```